# JNA Pointer class: How to set Pointer object to point to another class?

Tags: java, pointers, jna

I am trying to create a single Pointer object using the JNA library and set it to "point" to an object of a custom data type defined.

Can someone please explain how to do this?

```
CustomType ctype = new CustomType();
Pointer pointer = new Pointer(ctype);
```

This does not work. I have tried searching and googling but none of the questions I found have shown what I need.

Comment: How do you expect your native code to use the pointer you give it?

Comment: It should write something into the custom data type. A set of numbers which can be translated to status codes.

Comment: This might be answering my own question but it seems I should define the custom data type as a sublase of structure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, so as I stated in the comment, the sollution was to make the custom data type a subclass of JNA structure which has a getPointer() method.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subclass of [`com.sun.jna.Structure`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/Structure.html) and pass that object directly to your mapped method.  JNA will automatically take care of synchronizing the native data and pass a pointer to that data to the native method.

Refer to JNA's documentation on [how to use Structures](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/StructuresAndUnions.md) and [the FAQ](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#when-should-i-use-structurebyreference-structurebyvalue-structure).

Comment: I'm trying but I can't instantiate an object of this new class for some reason. I made a separate question here if you have any thoughts: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29010272/jna-cant-create-object-of-structure-subclass-invalid-structure-field