# JNA: Can't create object of structure subclass - Invalid structure field

Tags: java, jna

I am mapping a C typedef to a JNA Struct. Below if the C typedef:

```
typedef struct _GLYCOUNTERS {
unsigned int ulArraySize;
LPGLYCOUNTER lpCounters;
}GLYCOUNTERS, *LPGLYCOUNTERS;
```

And this is my JNA Structure subclass:

```
public class GlyCounters extends Structure{
    public class ByReference extends GlyCounters implements Structure.ByReference {};
    public class ByValue extends GlyCounters implements Structure.ByValue {};
    public int ulArraySize;
    public GlyCounter lpCounters;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ulArraySize", "lpCounters"});
}
    }
```

I am trying to create and object of GlyCounters class with code:

```
lppCounters = glyTypes.new GlyCounters();
```

As you can see I am creating the object in another class and GlyCounters is a nested class of yet another class.

This is the error message I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Structure field in class btc_dll.GloryTypeDef$GlyCounters, field name 'lpCounters' (class btc_dll.GloryTypeDef$GlyCounter): Can't instantiate class btc_dll.GloryTypeDef$GlyCounter (java.lang.InstantiationException: btc_dll.GloryTypeDef$GlyCounter)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.validateField(Structure.java:1038)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.validateFields(Structure.java:1048)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:179)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:172)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:159)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:151)
at btc_dll.GloryTypeDef$GlyCounters.<init>(GloryTypeDef.java:298)
at btc_gui.Btc_gui.main(Btc_gui.java:54)
Java Result: 1
```

The field causing the problem is yet another JNA Structure class for another c     typedef struct. After googling the error message, I have tried adding no-args constructors to both of these classes but the error still remains.

Has anyone had similar problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want a field of type `struct *` within your structure, you need to use a `Structure` tagged with the interface `Structure.ByReference`.

**EDITED**

The most common way to do this:

```
public class GlyCounter extends Structure {
    public class ByReference extends GlyCounter implements Structure.ByReference {};
    // More definition here...
}
public class GlyCounters extends Structure{
    public int ulArraySize;
    public GlyCounter.ByReference lpCounters;

    public GlyCounters(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
        read();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "ulArraySize", "lpCounters"});
    }
}

// To obtain the full array (assuming they're allocated as a block)
GlyCounters gc = new GlyCounters(pointer);
GlyCounter[] counters = gc.lpCounters.toArray(gc.ulArraySize());
```

The field `lpCounters` is now of pointer type instead of inlined (i.e. sharing the memory of the enclosing `struct`).

Comment: I don't understand how this applies to the current problem. The field that is causing the problem is a struct not a struct * as far as i can tell.
I have tryied implementing your advice as best as I was able but I still get the compilation error.
Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The name of the field and its type, "lpCounters" and `LPGLYCOUNTER`, would imply that it is of pointer type.

Comment: This code doesn't throw errors in Netbeans but it does require the addition of constructors for the ByReference and ByValue fields. The IDE generated constructors with paramater pointer p and a single call to super with the parameter. Can you tell me if this will be sufficient for the purpose I described?

Comment: I left the constructors out for clarity.  Normally a `Pointer`-based constructor and a no-args constructor are sufficient.  Most `Pointer`-based constructors should look like the one given for `GlyCounters`.

Comment: I'm still having issues with this part of the project. In your example when instantiating the class you assign GlyCounters a pointer. Where does it come from?
I have to pass this struct to java method mapped to a c function and data should be written into it but i'm not getting anything sensible back.

Comment: You can omit the pointer if you don't already have one and JNA will allocate the memory (including that for the struct array).  I used a pointer there simply to illustrate that if your native code has already provided you with some memory, you should use that.